# Can quantum field excitations propagate faster than light?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, causality, faster-than-light

(Let's assume we are in the Klein-Gordon free field theory)

If we had e.g. a localised field configuration (i.e. field state which is a field configuration eigenstate) at $t=0$. (By localised field configuration at $t=t_0$, I mean let the field configuration have field value $0$ everywhere except for a localised region)

This would evolve over time into a *superposition* of fields configurations at $t=t_1$

At $t=t_1$, would any field configuration in this superposition contain a non-zero field value in a region further than $d=c(t_1-t_0)$ from any positions with non-zero intial field?

---

**My Thoughts**

(I guess this may be similar to the cliche question of 'can virutal particles travel faster than light', although we're not talking about an interacting theory here.)

Obviously in the path integral formalism we integrate over all paths of field configurations, even those that would include situations like this (where the field configurations are vastly different between moments in time) -  but all these contributions sum to some 'actual' field evolution.

And I'm double checking whether this 'actual field evolution' would ever allow a situation like the above. (I'm guessing not, since its like asking the question - if we had some (indefinite) number of particles but all localised to some region, is there a chance that we could measure some time later that one of the particles had travelled faster than light)

I'm also wondering what exactly have we input into our formalism that stops this - is it the locality of the canonical commutation relations maybe, or simply the fact that the field operator evolves via the relativistic covariant KGE, or both?

Comment: One guess at a solution - since the intial field configuration eigenstate could be created by acting with some function of the field operator on the vacuum state (i.e. $F[\hat \phi(x)]|0>$ and since the field operator itself evolves via the relativistic Klein-Gordan equation, surely the possible field configuraitons in the resulting superposition at $t=t_1$ must too?